# jquery not Calling

Tags: jquery, asp.net

im using aspx and jquery> i was include my jquery in my project but it seem not working well. as i tested to call a simple alert() but it not calling at all. No error, no bugs prompt at my side. Im using chrome for testing.

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Testing Miss</title>

<link href="./css/missingkids.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" /> 

<script src="./script/missingkids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="PageLoad()">
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div class="bgcolor"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <input type="button" id="clickMe" value="click" />
    <div id="images">
        <img class="grayscale" src="image/img1.jpg" />
    </div>
```

In my JS file

```
(function($) {
$.fn.ibox = function() {
    ...
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#images img").ibox();
});


$("#clickMe").click(function () {

    alert("Me");
});



function PageLoad()
{
    var html = "";
    var num = 1;

    for (var idx=0; idx<100; idx++)
    {
        if( num == 4) num = 1;
        html += "<img src='image/img" + num + ".jpg' class='grayscale' />";
        num ++;
    }  
    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML  = html;
    //alert("adsf");

}
```

But my issues was seem jquery is not working as i tested the code with a button just to call alert but noting show.
Pls help

Thanks

Comment: are you sure there is not java-script error?

Answer (score 0):

please add your click event handler to document ready tag like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickMe").click(function () {
        alert("Me");
    });

    $("#images img").ibox();
});
```

you can write the document ready tag shorter like this:

```
$(function() {
    //...
});
```

and why you make a PageLoad when you have the Document ready tag? its the same... :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your correction and it really working now for alert().

Comment: However my next issues was actually $("#images img").ibox was calling the function as below:

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong order.

```
<script src="./script/missingkids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code above  should be written in such an order:

```
<script src="./script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script/missingkids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should also use google-chrome's developer tools or firefox's firebug to inspect the error console.

Comment: HI, Thanks a lot about your correction, i never know that the arrangement was so important.